# Auto Update Last Updated on Excel With VBA

Tags: vba, excel

1. I have a list of Cells that I will need to update. For example: i need to update cells("H 6:Q 11") and H 13:Q 18 and H 20:Q 25 and so on and so forth.  Within each range of cells, so long as i update one of the cells ( for example H 7 ), i want Cell D 6 to put my last updated date.  If i didn't update anything on H 13:Q 18, i want Cell D 13 to remain as it is. Is this possible to code?
2. I tried something similar to the code below but it didn't work

**Code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim xCellColumn As Integer
Dim xTimeColumn As Integer
Dim xRow, xCol As Integer 

xCellColumn = 2
xTimeColumn = 1
xRow = Target.Row
xCol = Target.Column

If Target.Text <> "" Then
    If xCol = xCellColumn Then
        Cells(xRow, xTimeColumn) = Now()
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work"? It should run if you change something in column B.

Answer (score 0):

Disable events and process possible multiple target cells.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H6:Q11, H13:Q18, H20:Q25")) Is Nothing Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H:Q"), Range("6:1048576")) Is Nothing Then
        'Debug.Print Target.Address(0, 0)
        On Error GoTo safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim rng As Range
        For Each rng In Intersect(Target, Range("H:Q"), Range("6:1048576"))
            If (rng.Row Mod 7) <> 5 Then
                Cells(rng.Row, "D").Offset(((rng.Row Mod 7) <> 6) * ((rng.Row Mod 7) + 1), 0) = Now
            End If
        Next rng
    End If
safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Jeeped,  i have used your code, but the cells does not automatically change. Neither can i run it using F5. Can you help on this?

Comment: Did you put the code in the worksheet's private code sheet and **not** in a public module code sheet? Did you crash Application.EnableEvents? Put Application.EnableEvents = True in the vbe's Immediate window and hit enter.

Comment: Shouldn't that first `EnableEvents` actually assign to `False`?

Comment: i just copied your formula and paste it on an empty module. I assumed that will be in private since we private sub it. Where do i need to put application.enableevents=true?